# If $f>0$ is discontinuous and bounded on $I$, is there a $g>0$ bounded such that $fg$ is continuous at least at one point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a closed and bounded interval and let
$$f:I\to(0,\infty)$$
be a bounded function that is discontinuous at every point in $I$.

Does there exist a bounded function $g:I\to(0,\infty)$ such that the product $fg$ is continuous at least at one point in $I$?

Comment: How about $g=17/f$?

Comment: Oups, I forgot to specify bounded... Let me edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Let $f(x) = 1/2^n$ if $x = m/2^n$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and 1 otherwise.  If $fg$ is continuous at $x_0$, then for some $a>0$ we have $g(x) \approx a/f(x)$ near $x_0$.  Then you can show that $g$ is unbounded.  (In fact, it is unbounded in every neighborhood of $x_0$.)

Do you see how to make this argument precise?